# how to fix javascript refresh error on google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have an error which is giving me a hard time to fix. I have written a program in JavaScript but when I refresh it doesn't affect the page. I even closed and opened the browser more than once but it didn't work, please does anyone have a solution to it?

This is some part of the code

```
var person = document.getElementById('formant');
var fname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
var lname = document.getElementById('lname').value;
var email = document.getElementById('email').value;
var num = document.getElementById('num').value;
var pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
var conpass = document.getElementById('conpass').value;
var gen ='';
function setgen(f)
{
    gen = document.getElementById(f).value;
}

person.addEventListener('submit', red);

function red(m)
{

    m.preventDefault();

    var xhr  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // var response = document.getElementById().innerHTML;
    xhr.open('POST','php/signupajax.php',true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onload = function()
    {
        if(this.status == 200)
        {
            if(document.getElementById('pass').value.lenght < 0)
    {
        alert('less man');
    }
          console.log(this.responseText);

        }
    }

    xhr.send('fname=' + document.getElementById('fname').value + '&lname=' + document.getElementById('lname').value + '&email=' + document.getElementById('email').value + '&num=' +document.getElementById('num').value+ '&pass=' + document.getElementById('pass').value + '&conpass=' +document.getElementById('conpass').value + '&gen=' + gen);

}
if(document.getElementById('pass').value <6)
{
  alert('password not strong');
}
else{
alert('password good');
}
```

Comment: look in the browser **developer** tools console for errors - the good news is, the code is "valid" - but without seeing the associated HTML, or knowing where this code is in your HTML, it's hard to help

Comment: i have checked the console and no errors have been displayed, but another funny part is that in the sources page/section the code i wrote is not displaying there... i have saved the work

Comment: so your javascript isn't even loading?

Comment: sorry for the late reply @JaromandaX but yes my javascript isn't loading and i don't know why, anytime it happens i have to restart my pc to solve the issue

Comment: you have to restart the PC!!! I don't think the issue is with the code you've posted in that case

Comment: i don't know if it is chrome that's causing the issues